# Change style of only the top first anchor in the list

Tags: css

I want to change the color of first **anchor** inside the **ul** element that has a text **Parent 1**

Here is my **html**

```
<ul class="Active">
<li>
<a>Parent 1</a>
<ul>
    <li><a>Child 1.1</a></li>
    <li><a>Child 1.2</a></li>
     <li><a>Child 1.3</a></li>
    <li> <a>Child 1.4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my **css**

```
.Active a:first-of-type{
  color:red;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/da8yxd8h/)

Comment: .Active li ul li:first-child a { color:red; }

Comment: no sory actually i want to highlight  The one with Parent1

Comment: you need to show more of your html structure

Comment: IT is just working for 1st child

Comment: why dont you go for jquery or javascript. Because its more conditional

Comment: @krishnar JS is overkill for this! CSS can easily achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first of type for the direct descendent of the parent `ul`, try this:

```
.Active > li:first-of-type > a {
  color: red;
}
```

The `>` selector will target direct children only, not "grandchildren", so its it targeting the *first* `li` element that is a direct descendent of `.Active`, and then getting the any `a` element that is a direct child of it.
(`first-of-type` will apply the color only to the first `li`, just in case it may have more children in your actual code).

```css
.Active > li:first-of-type > a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="Active">
  <li>
    <a>Parent 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Child 1.1</a></li>
      <li><a>Child 1.2</a></li>
      <li><a>Child 1.3</a></li>
      <li> <a>Child 1.4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: will you explain it in one line what this selector is doing

Comment: Great catch @FluffyKitten

Comment: @LSKhan Glad to help! FYI I noticed I'd a mixup in my explanation... I described having the `first-of-type` on the `a` instead of `li` - I've updated it now. Either would work with your current HTML, by the way - its only if you add more elements that it would change the result.

Comment: Great thanks but i got an idea from your solution and it works for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Only  on root level:

```
.Active > li > a {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this. Also try to start your class names with lower-case letters. It's better practice.

```
   .Active li ul li:first-child a { 
      color:red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :first-child selector to accomplish this.

```css
.Active ul > :first-child {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="Active">
<li>
<a>Parent 1</a>
<ul>
    <li><a>Child 1.1</a></li>
    <li><a>Child 1.2</a></li>
     <li><a>Child 1.3</a></li>
    <li> <a>Child 1.4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Hope it Helps. Cheers!

Comment: not wokring my expect output is to make the first achor with text **Parent 1** red